# How to connect a switch to a wireless network?

Tags: networking, router, switch, wifi

We've got a wireless modem which I don't have direct access and now I need to connect 15 PCs to it. These PCs all wired and connected to my 24 port switch.

Now how can I make my switch to connect this wireless network so all these 15 PCs can connect to the internet as well.

As I said I can't plug anything wired to main wireless modem, so it has to be wireless connection between my switch and the main wireless modem.

Comment: What brand and model is your Wireless modem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a Wifi AP. Most can be run in client mode, and connect to the modem's AP.

Comment: could you recommend a brand which can run in client mode?

Comment: Most can run in client mode, I know that a XyXEL one my folks had can.

Answer (score 3):

I've used an AP set up in bridging mode to connect a switch to a WiFi environment, it worked just fine.

Comment: how do I know if my router will support this configuration? I have a Billion bipac 7402nx and can see a bridging interface but I've never worked with this kind of setup before so I'm not sure what to look out for.

Answer (score 2):

linksys routers will do that (that is all I have experience with).  I currently run a Linksys WRT54GL v1.1 with Tomato firmware.  This is an upgrade from the stock linksys firmware.  It unlocks a few more features than the stock firmware will.  If you want an even more advanced firware use dd-wrt.  alot more features, alot more complicated.  I have used both and for my needs, tomato works well at home.

Answer (score 1):

DDWRT running on a Linksys WRT54G can act as a repeater.  I have never attempted it before, but have a look at the documentation.  I would think it would work.

Its at dd-wrt.com

Answer (score 0):

I'm running several Linksys WAP54G in a shared neighbourhood WiFi-Network. They are a cheap choice for a device that supports client mode.

However, I noticed several of those to switch their MAC address out of the blue. That does not go very well with MAC adresse filters ...